# PHP convert a MM/DD/YYYY string to a MMDDYYYY

Tags: php, date

I have a string representing a date. It's format is  `MM/DD/YYYY`.
 I need to submit it via API to a service that requires `MMDDYYYY`.
 Should I bother with overloading this string onto some date class and 'export' as `MMDDYYY` or just delete the "/" sub-string wherever I find it?

**Any other neat way of doing that I wasn't aware of?**

Comment: You can use [`date_parse_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) to parse the date, and `date()` to reformat it.

Comment: If you're confident the format is stable your solution would work and be simplest.

Comment: The question is mostly one of how much you trust your string, i'd think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DateTime object in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Here is how I would do it:

```
<?php

$myDate = '05/15/2015';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i:s', "$myDate 00:00:00");
$newDate = $date->format('mdY');

echo $newDate . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you just need to remove the '/' I would do that with the following code, it will eliminate the overhead of parsing the date.

```
$newDate =  str_replace ('/', '', $oldDate);
```